# Difference between density matrix and completeness relation

Tags: quantum-computing

The expression for completeness relation in quantum mechanics is -

```
Σ |ψ_n><ψ_n| = 1
```

where the expression for density matrix in statistical mechanics is -

```
ρ = Σ p_n |ψ_n><ψ_n|
```

Both of the equation looks the same. So what are the differences between the density matrix and completeness relation?

What is the basic difference between them?

Comment: This question is probably better asked in a forum more focused on quantum mechanics

Answer (score 0):

Formally the difference is that for the density matrix there are pre-factors `p_n` which sum up to 1 rather than all being 1 as in the completeness relation.

The meaning is also quite different.

Here is a rough illustration what they mean:
This object is a projection operator:
`|ψ_n><ψ_n|`
It projects on the `n-th` basis vector.
For simplicity lets take a simple example. Say our Hilbert space is 3 dimensional. Then the sum runs from 1 to 3. Each so-called pure state can be represented by a vector of length 1 in a 3 dimensional space like these examples:

```
|ψ_1> = (1, 0, 0)T
|ψ_2> = (0, 1, 0)T
|ψ_3> = (0, 0, 1)T
|φ> := (0, 1/2^0.5, 1/2^0.5)T
```

(The "T" stands for transposed)
These projection operators can be written as a matrix like for example:

```
             / 0  0  0 \
|ψ_2><ψ_2| = | 0  1  0 |
             \ 0  0  0 /
```

Now what these projection operators do is projecting a vector on one of the coordinate axes. E.g. for n=2 we project to the `y`-axis.

```
|ψ_2><ψ_2|φ> = (0, 1/2^0.5, 0)
```

Now what the completeness relation says is that the sum of those 3 vectors you get when projection on each coordinate axis is once again the original vector (see [Basis Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#/media/File:3d_two_bases_same_vector.svg)).
As this is true for any vector, this means the operation is the identity matrix:

```
                                       / 1  0  0 \  +   / 0  0  0 \  +   / 0  0  0 \     / 1 0 0 \
|ψ_1><ψ_1| + |ψ_2><ψ_2| + |ψ_3><ψ_3| = | 0  0  0 |  +   | 0  1  0 |  +   | 0  0  0 |  =  | 0 1 0 |  =  1
                                       \ 0  0  0 /  +   \ 0  0  0 /  +   \ 0  0  1 /     \ 0 0 1 /
```

Now the density matrix is a completely different matter. The weights `p_n` describe how one state is a mixture of several "pure" states. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix